# SQL Select virtual columns reference virtual columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I do not even know how to correctly formulate my question but basically I have this Select statement in Azure SQL Server (Transact-SQL):

**This does not Work:**

```
SELECT 
  Person.PersonID,
  Person.DisplayName, 
  VacationRequest.VacationYear,
  SUM(code for VacApp) AS VacApp,
  SUM(code for VacPen) AS VacPen,
  (VacApp + VacPen) AS VacBal
FROM Person
INNER JOIN VacationRequest ON Person.PersonID = VacationRequest.PersonID
GROUP BY Person.PersonID,Person.DisplayName, VacationRequest.VacationYear;
```

Everything works fine except the last column VacBal I get SQL Error:

```
"Failed to execute query. Error: Invalid column name 'VacApp'. Invalid column name 'VacPen'."
```

If I switch up my statement to not use VacApp and VacPen and put their SUM functions in their places it works. However, then the SQL code get messy since my SUM() functions are quite long and complex.

**This Works:**

```
SELECT 
  Person.PersonID,
  Person.DisplayName, 
  VacationRequest.VacationYear,
  SUM(code for VacApp) AS VacApp,
  SUM(code for VacPen) AS VacPen,
  (SUM(code for VacApp) + SUM(code for VacPen)) AS VacBal
FROM Person
INNER JOIN VacationRequest ON Person.PersonID = VacationRequest.PersonID
GROUP BY Person.PersonID,Person.DisplayName, VacationRequest.VacationYear;
```

I could use this but it is going to be a lot harder to understand after few years what the heck I did here. Also, If I switch up SUM function for VacApp I will need to remember to copy paste it for VacBal.

Is there a way to simplify this, like using (VacApp + VacPen) AS VacBal?
Also how are those columns created in SELECT statement called (columns created using functions like SUM, or when they combine few columns into one)? I call them Virtual Columns but I am sure this is not correct naming.

Comment: You could always comment your code to remind yourself/others why you wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the values, you will need a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT vpr.*,  (VacApp + VacPen) AS VacBal
FROM (SELECT p.PersonID, p.DisplayName,  vr.VacationYear,
             SUM(code for VacApp) AS VacApp,
             SUM(code for VacPen) AS VacPen
      FROM Person p JOIN
           VacationRequest vr
           ON p.PersonID = vr.PersonID
      GROUP BY p.PersonID, p.DisplayName, vr.VacationYear
     ) vrp;
```

Notice that table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery/CTE::

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    Person.PersonID,
    Person.DisplayName, 
    VacationRequest.VacationYear,
    SUM(code for VacApp) AS VacApp,
    SUM(code for VacPen) AS VacPen
  FROM Person
  INNER JOIN VacationRequest ON Person.PersonID = VacationRequest.PersonID
  GROUP BY Person.PersonID,Person.DisplayName, VacationRequest.VacationYear
)
SELECT *,  (VacApp + VacPen) AS VacBal
FROM  cte;
```

Or use CROSS/OUTER APPLY:

```
  SELECT 
  Person.PersonID,
  Person.DisplayName, 
  VacationRequest.VacationYear,
  SUM(s1.col_name) AS VacApp,
  SUM(s2.col_name) AS VacPen,
  (SUM(s1.col_name) + SUM(s2.col_name)) AS VacBal
FROM Person
INNER JOIN VacationRequest ON Person.PersonID = VacationRequest.PersonID
OUTER APPLY (code for VAcApp) s1
OUTER APPLY (code for VacPen) s2
GROUP BY Person.PersonID,Person.DisplayName, VacationRequest.VacationYear;
```